# how can i make to wait application inside in timer without thread.sleep

Tags: c#

how can i make a loop inside in timer?
if i put these codes inside if ,
it works but i dont want thread.sleep

```
if (a==true)
{
no color codes
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
green color codes
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
}
```

BUT i want to make without thread.sleep

```
time = Function.Get_Server_Time(false);
dServer_Time = time.Rows[0]["ServerDate"].ToDateTime();
long msecs = 0;

if (dTimeDef!= null)
{
 msecs = (dServer_Time.Ticks - dTimeDef.Ticks) / 10000;
}

if (a==true)
{

 if (dTimeDef == null || msecs>500)
 {
 no color
 }
else
 {
 green color
 }
dTimeDef = dServer_Time;


}
```

how can i improve it. It doesnt work like that

Comment: if there is already a timer, code doesn't have to sleep or wait. do some operations when Timer tick happens

Comment: What type of UI? Windows Forms?

Comment: yea win forms .

Answer (score 1):

Based on your pseudocode, I don't think you need a delay. You need an event to fire every 300 milliseconds, and you want to handle that event by alternating a color in one of your controls.

The simplest approach is to use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) and set its interval to 300 milliseconds, like this:

```
private Timer myTimer; 

public void InitTimer()
{
    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Interval = 300; // in miliseconds
    myTimer.Start();
}
```

Also, I suggest you don't think of the color as alternating. Think of color as a function of time. Example: The following function will return a 0 or a 1, alternating every 300 milliseconds:

```
(current milliseconds ÷ 300) mod 2
```

You can then use the output of this function to determine what the current color ought to be.  This is going to be more efficient and consistent than reading the current color and deciding what to do with it each time.

Thus your event handler might be:

```
private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var green = (((float)System.Environment.TickCount / 300) % 2) != 0;
    SetColor( green ? Color.Green : Color.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await Task.Delay(*time in milliseconds*)`. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx) should help you with it.

Comment: the difference is that `await Task.Delay` doesn't block the thread while `Thread.Sleep` does